# ClosedXML creating a table from a range within a sheet

Tags: .net, excel, closedxml

I have been asked if it is possible to create a table from a range within a sheet containing data with ClosedXML.
From what I have been told it is very easy within Excel, to select a range and convert it into a table - so I thought for sure ClosedXML must be able to do the same thing.

I read in another post here (4 years old) that this was not possible with ClosedXML, so I'm wondering if this is still the case 4 years later.

I have looked in the docs for an answer, but I'm unable to find exactly what I am looking for.
The best I have found is this showcase, section [Create an Excel table with the data portion](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Showcase).

However, creating a range object and from that range creating a table object, doesn't affect the sheet from which the range was created I'm thinking.

So, how can one achieve this goal, if at all possible?

Comment: Do these examples help?  https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/tree/develop/ClosedXML.Examples/Tables

Comment: Not really. I have already looked that this and it is about adding a table of new data to a sheet. I need to convert a range of existing data to a table within a sheet, just as you would in Excel by marking a range and choosing Insert -> Table.

Comment: You might have to write your own.

Comment: Did you try `var table = range.CreateTable();` ?

Comment: But why would that change the sheet? As far as I know this just gives me a copy of what's in that range in a table object to work with - but does it update the sheet?